# AWS FIS Memory stress not stressing beyond 5-6%

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fis

I have been trying to use FIS to stress cpu and memory using ssm commands and watch the results using 'top' command in ubuntu. While cpu stress command pushes the cpu to 99.9%, the memory stress command (`AWSFIS-Run-Memory-Stress`) doesn't push %MEM beyond 5-6%.

This is my spec: `{"Percent":"95", "DurationSeconds":"30", "InstallDependencies":"True"}`

The experiments concludes successfully but I am not seeing the spike in the top command view.
Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: I tried increasing workers to 10 and it improved to 10 entries with 1.3% each (total 13%), still a lot less than what I thought it would do.

Comment: You can check the output of the stress-ng command in AWS Systems Manager after running the experiment in FIS. You can heck there for the latest SSM command run, maybe you find an error or something.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, I see that the output/error doesn't show anything as wrong/missing. I just see this msg which 'sort of' indicates everything is in order: stress-ng: info: [54750] dispatching hogs: 10 vm
stress-ng: info: [54750] successful run completed in 30.03s